# Block chmod over SFTP

Tags: sftp

Is it possible to block chmod over SFTP without patching the SSH daemon? I read somewhere that you can do this via ACLs although I am not quite sure how that is supposed to work.

Comment: Would you mind specifying which SSH server software and on which specific OS?

Answer (score 0):

By default as far as I know this is not possible however it is possible to patch SFTP by yourself.

Go check out the patch here: http://sftpfilecontrol.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a program called [authprogs](https://github.com/daethnir/authprogs/blob/master/doc/authprogs.md).